# Wanted to Transfer the file from one location to another location using Button in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I have an Excel file (say xyz.xlsx) on my server but want to fetch that file and save locally on my desktop, when ever i press the "Move" Button present on my form.Please guide me on this, that how it can be done. i am right now using visual studio 2017

Answer (score 1):

You have two easy options.

If you want to do this as a training exercise you look into the System.IO classes.

```
System.IO.File.Move(source$, destination$) will suffice.
```

You can improve this with some error checking such as

```
System.IO.Directory.Exists(sourcePath$)
System.IO.Directory.Exists(destPath$)
```

You can then play around with string formatting and error handling as you please.

If **All** you are doing is copy a file and that is your entire software, I would suggest doing it in CMD instead.

This same approach can be called from VB if needed.
Process.Start("ROBOCOPY " & source$ & " " & destination$ & " " & flags)

The advantage of doing this is it is a separate process to your main code, which means you can leave a very large file copying over a long period of time without hanging up your own code.

```
''' <summary>
''' Copies the file at destination Source to the folder DestinationPath (and creates the folder if it doesn't exist)
''' </summary>
''' <param name="Source">Format C:\Users\username\documents\randomstuff\unnecessaryfolder\newfolder\myfile.txt</param>
''' <param name="DestinationPath">Format (and Default path) C:\Users\username\Desktop\ </param>
Public Sub MoveFile(Source As String, DestinationPath As String)
    If DestinationPath = "" Then
        DestinationPath = "C:\Users\" & My.User.Name & "\Desktop\" 'default path
    End If
    Dim FileName
    Dim src() As String = Source.Split("\")
    FileName = src(src.Count - 1) 'returns the name of the file in the full path
    Try
        If Not IO.File.Exists(Source) Then Throw New Exception("Wrong file, you plonka!")
        If Not IO.Directory.Exists(DestinationPath) Then IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(DestinationPath)
        IO.File.Copy(Source, DestinationPath & FileName)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Follow up - I've just realised the HTML title for this page had "VB6" in it but the tag and question had VB.Net.   

For clarity, these are two very different languages.
The reply above is for VB.Net, however calling ROBOCOPY from VB6 will also work.